# Extract field from SQL XML

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I've searched on this website and internet but can't seem to get anything to work for this simple request.  I just want to display the word relating to the **term** e.g. using the xml column below **TEST** will be extracted.

The xml column is as below:

```
<A>
  <resources id="1" resourceType="Template" term="TEST" version="1" />
</A>
```

I've tried using the following but it returns NULLS.

```
select 
Res.value('(/A/term)[1]','nvarchar(50)') as 'Res'

from Con
where Res is not null
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
select 
Res.value('(/A/resources/@term)[1]','nvarchar(50)') as 'Res'

from Con
where Res is not null
```

`term` is an attribute (needs a `@` signum) within the element `<resources>` below `<A>`. Your xpath wans't reflecting this correctly...

Comment: As simple as that.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT T.tm.value('@term[1]','nvarchar(50)')  as 'Res'
FROM   Con  
CROSS APPLY Res.nodes('/A/resources') as T(tm)
```